# Laravel model belongs to current user and global user

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following collections:

**User**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mary"
}
```

**Stuff**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "Bob's stuff"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "Mary's stuff"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 0,
    "name": "Everyone's stuff"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": null,
    "name": "Global stuff"
}
```

... and the following models:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function stuff() {
        return $this -> hasMany( 'Stuff' ) ;
    }
}
class Stuff extends Eloquent {
    public function user() {
        return $this -> belongsTo( 'User' ) ;
    }
}
```

How to I automatically add Everyone's stuff ( User.id == 0 ) and Global stuff ( User.id == null ) to everybody's model?  In other words, if I was querying for Bob's stuff I wish to get the following:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "Bob's stuff"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 0,
    "name": "Everyone's stuff"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": null,
    "name": "Global stuff"
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between Global stuff and Everyone's stuff? Why is your relationship to `Stuff` called `cards()`?

Comment: No there is no difference between Global's and Everyone's stuff... I just wanted the flexibility to be able to append based on different user_id. Maybe a better word instead of Everyone would be Department's stuff.

`cards()` was just a copy-n-paste error. I have updated the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
public function stuff() {
    return $this->hasMany(Stuff::class)->orWhere('user_id', 0)->orWhereNull('user_id');
}
```

A disadvantage is that you can't just add other `WHERE` clauses:

```
$user->stuff()->where('foo', 'bar')->get(); // Doesn't work as expected.
```

As a consequence, eager loading doesn't work.

Comment: Those disadvantages are required for my app.  I guess I will just need to update my controllers.